# Firefox scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a ajax call that works fine except that FF slowly scrolls top. Any ideas what could be the reason fo this.

```
$("#delete-team-dialog .btn-danger").unbind("click").click(function () {
    var contextPath = $.trim($("#context_path").text());

    $.ajax({
        type : 'DELETE',
        url :  contextPath + "/team/" + teamId,
        cache : false,
        success : function(data) {
            $(li).closest(".entered_teams_container").find(".number-of-teams").text(numberOfTeams -1);
            li.remove();
            $("#delete-team-dialog").modal('hide');
            startFormChanged();
            updateNumberOfParticipants();
            //If no teams left reload the page for redirect.
            if($(".team-row").length === 0){
                window.location.reload(true);
            }

        },  
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("....");
        }

    });

});
```

Edit: Some HTML

```
                <ul class="entered_teams">
                    <#list class6 as team>
                    <li class="row-fluid team">

                        <div class="span2">${((team.heat.date)?string("HH:mm"))!}</div>
                        <div class="span7 team">
                            ${team.enrollment.organization.name!?html}, 6. trinn, lag${team.number?c} <#if !team.complete ><i class="icon-warning-sign text-error"></i></#if>
                        </div> 
                            <span class="delete pull-right"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</span>  
                            <span class="edit pull-right">
                            <i class="pencil"></i> Edit</span>

                        <div class="team_setup row-fluid">
                            <button class="btn update-event-button">Save</button>
                        </div> <span class="team-id hidden">${team.id?c}</span>
                    </li> 
                    </#list>
                </ul
```

Comment: You have no code that causes scrolling posted. Impossible to say why it scrolls. The only thing I see is your call to `reload` which would cause the user to return to the top of the page, but this wouldn't have slow scrolling.

Comment: I dont understand either. I is not a problem in chrome.

Comment: You need to post some html here, I agree with sherman this probably isn't the source of the issue.